# Query to find values that occur during time interval where start time is from previous day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Good day,

I'm trying the below SQL query to return all values that occurred between 23:00 HRS to 04:00hrs, regardless of date.

The query works if the start time is smaller than the end time e.g 04:00 hrs - 08:00hrs.
The column 'time' is a datetime variable
 How can I make this work?

```
SELECT AVG(Taxi) AS Average,capacity, name, time
FROM Stations s, TaxiUsage b
WHERE s.usageID=b.stationId AND TIME(b.time)>= '23:00:00' AND TIME(b.time)<'04:00:00'
GROUP BY time;
```

The above query runs but returns 'Empty set'

Comment: Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation. Use the newer JOIN keyword. (Can we really still call that "newer"? The comma syntax is just getting really, really old.) Also, relocate the join predicate(s) from the WHERE clause to the `ON` clause. And empty set is the expected result, since we are guaranteed that no value `b.time` can satisfy both of those conditions. Those conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback..will implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, learn proper `JOIN` syntax.  Second, do not include columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` or arguments to aggregation functions.
Then, use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT time, AVG(Taxi) AS Average
FROM Stations s JOIN
     TaxiUsage u
     ON s.usageID = u.stationId 
WHERE TIME(b.time) >= '23:00:00' OR TIME(b.time)<'04:00:00'
GROUP BY time;
```

Comment: You must be a joy to work with. Thanks the OR worked.